# getvertices with multiple keys,values is not working

Tags: orientdb

I am facing some issue with `getVertices` function

on calling get vertices function, I am getting empty result even though I have data

```
Iterable<Vertex> resultIterator = db.getVertices("Myclass", new String[] {"key1","key2"} , new String[]{"value1","value2"});
```

and (`key1+key2`) is my composite key (non-unique)

and if I query the same from studio I am getting results; example :

```
select from Myclass where key1='value1' and key2="value2"
```

am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: What type key1 and key2 are?

Comment: Key1 is string , key2 is integer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Iterable resultIterator=g.getVertices("MyClass",new String[] {"key1","key2"}, new Object[] {"value1",value2});
```

P.S. value2 must be an Integer

Regards